# Laravel Pluck Concat Relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, pluck

Im using laravel 8 to my project, trying to pluck data from a Model

```
    $user = Users::with('media')->get()->pluck('media.title', 'id')->all();
```

I got the Output

```
    {
     "sample": 1,
    }
```

My expected output,Looking for the value combine a column from media table and column from user table

```
   {
     "media.title + user.name": id,
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge this isn't possible with pluck directly. You have 2-3 options the way I see it:

Either make an accessor in your `User` model which concatenates the user name and the media title, something like:

```
public function getNameWithMediaAttribute()
{
    return $this->name . ' + ' . $this->media->title
}
```

Which you then pluck with `->pluck('nameWithMedia')` after your query.

---

Or you can pull them the way you did with `$user = Users::with('media')->get();` and map over the result to return the format you want. Something like:

```
$users = User::with('media')->get()->map(function($user) 
{
    return [$user->media->title . ' + ' . $user->name => $user->id];
})->collapse();
```

Don't forget about the `->collapse()` part.

---

You could also make a query which gathers that data under one field and then you pluck it after pulling it from the database. But my SQL-fu isn't good enough to do that easily.